# Automatically create zip file with dependencies for AWS Lambda - Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, package, zip

I am building a script which automatically builds AWS Lambda function. I follow [this github repo](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/python/example_code/lambda/boto_client_examples/lambda_basics.py) as an inspiration.

However, the lambda_handler that I want to deploy is having extra dependencies, such as `numpy`, `pandas`, or even `lgbm`. Simple example below:

```py
import numpy as np 

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    result = np.power(event['data'], 2)

    response = {'result': result}
    return response
```

example of an event and its response:

```py
event = {'data' = [1,2,3]}
lambda_handler(event)
> {"result": [1,4,9]}
```

I would like to automatically add the needed layer, while creating the AWS Lambda. For that I think I need to change `create_lambda_deployment_package` function that is in the `lambda_basic.py` in the repo. What I was thinking of doing is a following:

```py
import zipfile
import glob
import io

def create_full_lambda_deployment_package(function_file_name):

    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(buffer, 'w') as zipped:
        # Adding all the files around the lambda_handler directory 
        for i in glob.glob(function_file_name):
            zipped.write(i)

        # Adding the numpy directory
        for i in glob.glob('./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/*'):
            zipped.write(i, f'numpy/{i[41:]}')
    buffer.seek(0)
    return buffer.read()
```

Despite the fact that lambda is created and 'numpy' folder appears my lambda environment, unfortunately this doesn't work (error `cannot import name 'integer' from partially initialized module 'numpy' (most likely due to a circular import) (/var/task/numpy/__init__.py)"`).

How could I fix this issue? Or is there maybe another way to solve my problem?

Comment: So next time please make your question clear and specific. No such information about pandas is even given.

Comment: It did say 'extra dependencies' from the beginning, not specifically `numpy`, but thanks.

Comment: Fair enough. My mistake. Sorry.